# Write to File skips last 10-20 lines

Tags: c#, stream, streamwriter, file.readalllines

First i Read all lines of a text file line by line and store it in a string-array.
Then i write it with file.WriteLine() into a file.
The opened Console window shows every line which was written into the file, but when i open the file to check if it did well, the last 10-20 lines are missing.

Any ideas?

```
 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Dok1.csv");
            StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test2.csv");
            
            foreach(string line in lines)
            {
                file.WriteLine(line);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

[image: Console output: Redunderlined is the last line]

[image: Comparison Written File vs. Read File(Written file is missing last lines)]

Comment: You don't dispose your `StreamWriter` -- it will be buffering some text internally, which never gets flushed. Using a `using` block

Comment: Are your lines fixed length? perhaps https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Data.Analysis

Comment: @canton7 ahhh, well, that was quick. 
It worked with the using-block. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using(StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\test2.csv"))
    {
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            file.WriteLine(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

The [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) closes the stream forcing the write of the internal buffer.